# Deploy Django 1.10 app with python 3.6 on Google Compute Engine

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, django-deployment

I have created a project using with Django 1.10.5 and python 3.6, now I need to deploy this project on google compute engine.I have googled a lot but couldn't find any clear guide to deploy my Django app on compute engine.

What I have tried:

1. Create a compute engine instance
2. Install python 3.6 (But not succeded that's why using pre-installed python 3.5.2)
3. Setup pip and virtualenv
4. Create a virtualenv and clone my project from GitHub
5. Install all requirements from requirements.txt
6. now when I try to run my app as `python manage.py runserver` from my directory, it says :

> Django version 1.10.5, using settings 'brain.settings'
>
> Starting development server at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`
>
> Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

1. when I visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` doesn't load any page.

How can I deploy my Django 1.10 & Python 3.6 app on google compute engine?
Help me, please!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you open port 8000 on GCP firewall?

Comment: Hi, @user! do i need to add a firewall rule with port tcp:8000 ?

Comment: yes, TCP. And for your upcoming question: You should keep in mind, that GCP doesn't allow you to [send mails with port TCP:25](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/) and you'll need an extra provider for that.

Comment: i have added that but still not loading!

Comment: replace `127.0.0.1` with the public IP of your GCP instance

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Do you need further assistance on this issue?

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is to add a new incoming Firewall rule on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) for `TCP:8000`.

To do so simply connect to your [GCP: Console Firewall Rules](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/) and add a new rule.

Also be sure to launch Django to listen on the public interface and you to access with the public IP.

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: What error do you see in your browser? Does Django's `runserver` command print something?

Comment: Safari can't open this page!

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please post the IP of your instance so I can investigate it further?

Comment: I get an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` which means the Firewall rule isn't set correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156883/discussion-between-abdul-rehman-and-user1).